# Problem with using Ninject.Component.Get to force Ninject to clear cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I was reading Bob Cravens blog on Ninject and a problem they discovered with the GC.collect not being called efficiently.  The Ninject team provided Bob a way around this by having him add the following to the NinjectWebsiteApplication:

```
_kernel.Components.Get<ICache>().Clear(HttpContext.Current);
```

However, I get the error that ICache must be convertible to Ninject.Components.IComponentContainer and that Clear() takes 0 parameters. The Ninject team stated that would be addressing/including it in a future release.  However, I am not sure that it was yet being his blog was posted on 11/18.

I did find that I could:

```
_kernel.Get<ICache>().Clear();
```

But is this accomplishing the same thing, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not using the latest Ninject version. Try update to the RC1 found on https://github.com/ninject.

Another problem could be that your ICache is not from Ninject but another 3rd party component or your own code.

Comment: The latest version of the MVC and Web extension have this integrated by default. Can you check if thi works for you and give a feedback?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the newest version and MVC extensions. Happens mostly on local dev webserver.